# Continuous Functionals and Norms

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

In Luenberger Optimization book, pg. 40 upper semicontinuity for a functional is defined as "if given $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ s.t. $f(x) - f(x_0) < \epsilon$ for $||x-x_0|| < \delta$". Then it goes on as "a functional is said to be lower semicontinuous at $x_0$ if $-f$ is upper semicontinuous at $x_0$". Functional is continuous if it is both.

However later in the same page Example 1 talks about a functional $f$ defined on $C[0,1]$

$$
f(x) = \int_{0}^{1/2}x(t)dt - \int_{1/2}^{1}x(t)dt 
$$

and says "it is easily verified that f is continuous since, in fact, $|f(x)| \le ||x||$".

How did he make this connection? Where did $x_0$ go? And how come there is a relation between the functional and the norm on $x$?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ is linear, so $f(x)-f(x_0)=f(x-x_0)$. From this $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|f(x-x_0)|\le\Vert x-x_0\Vert$; from which continuity easily follows.

To see why $|f(x)|\le\Vert x\Vert$:
$$
|f(x)|=\biggl|\int_0^{1/2} x(t)\,dt -\int_{1/2}^1 x(t)\,dt \biggr|\le
\biggl|\int_0^{1/2} x(t)\,dt \biggr|+ \biggl| \int_{1/2}^1 x(t)\,dt \biggr|\le \textstyle {1\over2}\Vert x\Vert+ {1\over2}\Vert x\Vert=\Vert x\Vert.
$$

Comment: Hi David, how did you know the inequality $|f(x-x_0)|\le\Vert x-x_0\Vert$ ? This problem doesn't seem to define a norm for $C[0,1]$, or I missed it.

Comment: @user6786 It is the  supremum norm, defined in Example 1 on page 23. (The inequality $|f(x-x_0)|\le\Vert x-x_0\Vert$ follows directly from $|f(x)|\le \Vert x\Vert$.)

Comment: got it, thanks.

Comment: One more question, the derivation you've shown shows how to obtain the inequality $|f(x)| \le ||x||$. How do we conclude given this inequality, continuity should be correct as well? Without any use of $\epsilon,\delta$? I guess if $|f(x)| \le ||x||$ than $f(x) - f(x_0) < \epsilon$ for $||x-x_0|| < \delta$ should be automatically true also?

Comment: Yea that must be it. If there is direct relationship between $|f(x)|$ and $||x||$ no need to jump through the hoops and deal with $\epsilon,\delta$.

Comment: @user6786 Your thoughts on $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ seem right. More precisely, the David's answer shows that the function is [$1$-Lipschitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity). It is a general fact that all Lipschitz functions are continuous; the proof is an easy application of the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition. It is usually cleaner to prove that a function is Lipschitz: we can do away with $\varepsilon$'s and $\delta$'s.

Comment: @user6786 Here's a more specific fact about linear operators: A linear map $T$ between normed linear spaces is continuous if and only if it is bounded; i.e., iff there exists $M < \infty$ such that $\| Tx \| \leqslant M \|x \|$ for all $x$. I think the book is referring to this particular fact (with $M$ set to $1$).